# F# interactive shell (fsi) tutorial?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm learning F# with fsi on Mac OS X/mono, but it's hard to know what command to quit and out to shell.

quit, or ^D doesn't work, ^C also doesn't work. What's the command to to stop the fsi?

In general, where can I find some tutorial/user's guide about fsi?

Comment: If you have two questions, best to ask them seperately.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `#help;;` for help, `#quit;;` to quit.

Answer (score 13):

When I start F# in OS X/mono I get the following

```
~> fsi

Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 2.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;
```

By typing `#help` I get:

```
> #help;;

  F# Interactive directives:

    #r "file.dll";;        Reference (dynamically load) the given DLL
    #I "path";;            Add the given search path for referenced DLLs
    #load "file.fs" ...;;  Load the given file(s) as if compiled and referenced
    #time ["on"|"off""];;  Toggle timing on/off
    #help;;                Display help
    #quit;;                Exit

  F# Interactive command line options:

      See 'fsi --help' for options


>
```

These should provide your answers.

Comment: The last line should read "For help type #help;; To quit type #quit;;" - and that could cut down the confusion with a Pareto machete i.e. by 80%